# glPushMatrix inside display list duplicates models

Tags: opengl, displaylist

I have a display list for some cubes... very simple stuff. Here's a snippet:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix
GL11.glRotatef(90,0,0,1)
cuboid(1,0.5,20) //just glVertex calls
GL11.glPopMatrix
```

If I use this to draw in immediate mode nothing odd happens. However if I put this in a display list it will first draw the cuboid unrotated and then rotated (or whatever transformation I do between glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix). Moreover, if I don't use glPush and glPop it behaves as expected.

Is there something I should need to know when using glPush/PopMatrix in display lists?

EDIT: adding some more source code:

```
handle = GL11.glGenLists(1);
GL11.glNewList(handle,GL11.GL_COMPILE)
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);

GL11.glPushMatrix //if I don't use these it behaves as expected
GL11.glRotatef(90,0,0,1)
cuboid(1,0.5,20) //just glVertex calls
GL11.glPopMatrix

GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glEndList();
```

EDIT2: I've made it works by swapping glBegin with glPushMatrix and glEnd with glPopMatrix - I don't like how it looks now but at least it works. From what I know this is NOT normal and what I've done is just a trick, so I'm leaving the question open.

```
GL11.glPushMatrix //everytime I want to push/pop I have to call glBegin and glEnd
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
GL11.glRotatef(90,0,0,1)
cuboid(1,0.5,20) //just glVertex calls
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glPopMatrix
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error to call glPushMatrix inside of glBegin/glEnd. There's only a strict subset of commands that can be used inside of a glBegin/glEnd pair.

From glBegin man page:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd.
>               The commands are
>               glVertex,
>               glColor,
>               glSecondaryColor,
>               glIndex,
>               glNormal,
>               glFogCoord,
>               glTexCoord,
>               glMultiTexCoord,
>               glVertexAttrib,
>               glEvalCoord,
>               glEvalPoint,
>               glArrayElement,
>               glMaterial, and
>               glEdgeFlag.
>               Also,
>               it is acceptable to use
>               glCallList or
>               glCallLists to execute
>               display lists that include only the preceding commands.
>               If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd,
>               the error flag is set and the command is ignored.

On the man page for glPushMatrix:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glPushMatrix or glPopMatrix
>               is executed between the execution of glBegin
>               and the corresponding execution of glEnd.

Start putting glGetError in your development code, it will point out these kinds of problems to you.

Also glRotatef is not legal there either:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glRotate
>               is executed between the execution of glBegin
>               and the corresponding execution of glEnd.